# Python: Removing part of list and putting to columns in csv

Tags: python

I am using python, I have a list :

```
[ahref="/name<sdfjnsflnsdlkfnsdlf>Gender<sdlfknsldfnwlkfn>Country<dfnsdflnsdfsldn>This is a graduate student<yogm>,
ahref="/name<sdfjnsflnsdlkfnsdlf>Gender<sdlfknsldfnwlkfn>Country<dfnsdflnsdfsldn>This is a graduate student<yogm>,
ahref="/name<sdfjnsflnsdlkfnsdlf>Gender<sdlfknsldfnwlkfn>Country<dfnsdflnsdfsldn>This is a graduate student<yogm>]
```

I would like to:

1. remove `ahref=", <sdfjnsflnsdlkfnsdlf> , <sdlfknsldfnwlkfn> , <dfnsdflnsdfsldn> <yogm>`
2. include `abc.com` to `/name`
3. put the `abc.com/name , male , country` and `This is a graduate student` into different columns in CSV

For # 2, I managed to use the below to get it working

```
n [10]:
lobbying = {}
for element in letters:
    lobbying[element.a.get_text()] = {}

letters[0].a["href"]

prefix = "www.abd.com"

for element in letters:
    lobbying[element.a.get_text()]["link"] = prefix + element.a["href"]
```

Answer (score 0):

By using regular expressions:

```
import re
prefix = "www.abd.com"
for your_string in letters:
```

1)

```
    re.sub(r'(ahref=)|(<[^>]*>)', '', your_string)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ulO9N5/2/)

2)

```
    your_string.replace("/name",prefix+"/name")
```

This performs 1) and 2)

If you want to perform 3) I would recommend not executing 1) because removing the tags will eliminate delimiters, therefore you can no longer distinguish your fields. Just match everything non in tags. `(?![\^>])[^<>]+(?=<)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pmsfIM/1/)

Every string will return multiple matches you can put into your CSV.

Comment: thanks, just to clarify, "name" are all different              can you clarify what does this do  ? your_string.sub(r'(ahref=)|(<[^>]*>)', ' ', s)

Comment: Then instead of "/name" use a variable. So 2) works. And if you apply 3), it will also match the website url

Comment: your_string.sub(r'(ahref=)|(<[^>]*>)', ' ', s)  what does the r and s mean ? If it is a list, does the string replace work ?

Comment: I added demo links. Please click and see in the tool. It replaces it with nothing anyway (you asked to remove it)

Comment: so this works for a list and a string ? Or do i need to loop every item in the list ?

Comment: Right, loop them.`for your_str in your_array:`

Comment: I fixed a mistake. please look at 1) again. Now it works. By the way re stands for Regular Expression (regex)

Comment: @Lko I know. You are supposed to iterate the list. As I called it, your_string is a string... let me iterate it for you then (edited)